# How to show an alert / text box after submitting (button) an option value (from drop-down list)?

Tags: html, text, submit, alert, html-select

I can't seem to find how to make this work - selecting an option from the drop-down list & submitting it using a submit button then having an alert / text box show after after clicking submit button. Is it possible ? TIA

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide your code and what you are currently attempting to do, we do not write solutions for you but rather assist you with whatever problem's you're having in code and direct you towards the correct method of approach.

Answer (score 0):

What language do you use? if it web, you can add javascript to check your value dropdown.

you can add onSubmit on your form

Comment: This is what I can think of but all their alerts are same. How do I make an alert for each option ? <form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  <select name="food" id="food" form="foodform">
  <option value="bananas">Bananas</option>
  <option value="potatoes">Potatoes</option>
  <option value="broccoli">Broccoli</option>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("The form was submitted")}
</script>

Comment: umm... i think you can add onchange function for each your input.